# HTTPERROR 403 "Insuficiente permision"

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to request the users gmail data list messages and modify one of them. i am getting the following error

> HTTPERROR 403 “Insuficiente permision”

**code**

```
def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])
        response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',
                                                labelIds='INBOX').execute()
        messages = []
        if 'messages' in response:
            messages.extend(response['messages'])
        #print(messages)
        for i in messages:
            aux_id = i
            id = aux_id.get('id')
            print(id)
            message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=id).execute()
            #print (type(message))
            data = message.get('payload', {}).get('body',{}).get('data')
            data = data.decode('base64')
            list_of_dic = message.get('payload',{}).get('headers')
            #print(list_of_dic)
            #DATE, JUST NEED TO FORMAT IT TO YYYY/MM/DD
            for i in list_of_dic:
                if i['name'] == 'Date':
                    aux_date = i
                if i['name'] == 'From':
                    aux_sender = i
                if i['name'] == 'Subject':
                    aux_subject = i
            sender = aux_sender.get('value')
            date = aux_date.get('value')
            subject = aux_subject.get('value')
            print(date)
            print(sender)
            print(subject)
            print(data)## data from emaail working
            print('***************************************************')
            message = service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=id,
                                            body='INBOX').execute()
```

Comment: Could you add trace log of this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To ask a good question, it takes more than just copy / pasting your code and error message. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: @KlausD. I have edited his question i hope this enough information to make the issue clear to you.   By reading the code i was able to understand the problem but i have added text to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insuficiente permision can mean one of two things

1. the user you are authncated with does not have permission to do what you are trying to do.
2. The user has not granted your application enough permissions to do what you are trying to do.

As you are using user id of me then i think we can assume that the problem is not the first one.  A user by default would have access to access their data.  The issue is with the scopes of the permissions your application has requested and the user has granted.

[messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and [messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) require one of the following scopes to work.

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata

However [messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) requires one of the following scopes to work.

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

You have not mentioned what scopes you have requested.  I sugest that you check the scopes and make sure that you have requested enough permissions to modify the email. Make sure that you authenticate the user.

**Solution**

Check what you have SCOPES set to in this line

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
```

make sure to add either

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

Then run the code again so that it asks for the users consent again.

Comment: thank you DalmTo, but im not sure how i add scopes, is it on the credential files?

Comment: SCOPES <-- that is your scopes.  What do you have that variable set to.